# How can I upload image using groovy? my view is not gsp but rather html css. I have the following html tags

Tags: image-processing

This is an input html fields through which I want to upload image?

```
<form action="" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    Your image: <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Could somebody help me how this is done in grails

Answer (score 0):

view code

```
<g:form controller="yourController" action="yourAction" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  Your image: <input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</g:form>
```

Controller Code

```
def save_listing(){

        String storagePath = ""
        Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
            development {
                //def servletContext = ServletContextHolder.servletContext
                storagePath = "/your/path/to store/locally"
            }
            production {
                storagePath = "/opt/home/images"
            }
        }

        List<MultipartFile> files = request.multiFileMap.pic
        int count = files.findAll { !it.empty }.size
        for (int i = 0; i <files.size(); i++) {
            fileUploadService.uploadFile( files[i], "${i}.jpg", "${storagePath}/${Listing.findAll().size()+1}" )
        }

       render("success")


    }
```

Service Code

```
def String uploadFile(MultipartFile file, String name, String destinationDirectory ) {

    def storagePathDirectory = new File(destinationDirectory)
    if (!storagePathDirectory.exists()) {
        print "CREATING DIRECTORY ${destinationDirectory}: "
        if (storagePathDirectory.mkdirs()) {
            println "SUCCESS"
        } else {
            println "FAILED"
        }
    }

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        file.transferTo(new File("${destinationDirectory}/${name}"))
        println "Saved file: ${destinationDirectory}/${name}"
        return "${destinationDirectory}/${name}"
    } else {
        println "File ${file.inspect()} was empty!"
        return null
    }

}
```

This solution will help you to upload multiple image at a time.Good practice is upload image in directory no db .